# C++ WINAPI window visibliity toggling code

Tags: winapi, user-interface

How do I toggle between having a button or a window back and forth between being visible and not visible, I can't find the code that fits the problem.. I'm using CreateWindowEx to make the window. I tried googling for this answer and I can't find any example code on how to do this. also if you can toggle a window or button to the background or foreground that would be helpful as well. If you need any more info in order to answer the question let me know. Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think it's a stretch of the term to call any of the WINAPI's "C++".  They're all pretty much plain C.

Comment: o oops, my mistake, ty for correcting me on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - so to hide a window do this

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

and to show it again

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

where `hWnd` is the window handle.

To change the z-order of a window (i.e. to bring it forward or back) look at the [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in MSDN.

Comment: oh awesome!!! thanks so much! trying it right now